# Can a cookie be used to pass data from a web app on one server to a web app on a different server in the same domain?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, web-applications, webserver

I have been given the task of sending data from one application to another.  More than likely that the resources are on different web servers. I do not know yet,  so I am assuming that they are on different servers. However, they are in the same domain like the following:

```
http://a.bbb.com/SevletX
http://a.bbb.com/ServletY
```

I need to be able to send some sensitive data from the first resource to the second resource. Assuming that they are on 2 different servers, RequestDispatcher will not work.  I do not have the option of using query string as the data is sensitive information (user credential).

1. If I set a cookie in the first resource and redirect, will the cookie be available to the second resource? I do not have the environment where I can test this.
2. If the above is true, can I serialize an object, convert it into a string and then set the string value in the cookie and retrieve it in the second resource, deserialize and get the object back?
3. Would the cookie be safe enough (say over https)to send sensitive data such as user credentials?

Comment: Could you use a cookie for that? Yes. Should you? Generally speaking, no. Especially for credentials. I am not sure the use case but modern applications typically use token based authentication like oauth.

Comment: You say I could use cookies.  Does it matter if the web servers are on different physical machines? Also, it is really not an authentication issue.  I am not trying to do a single sign on.  However, I need to pass the data to the other web server where it is used to pass the data to a rich client via a JNLP file.   So I have to figure out a way of passing the data securely from web app1 to web app2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, as long as it is on the same computer.
2. Yes, you should be able to serialize it and retrieve the object from a different script.
3. And cookies are local so it wouldn't be sent over a domain.

Edit: You said they are likely on two different web servers so you wouldn't be able to share cookies and you should try a similar approach but instead store the data in a MYSQL server so both programs can have access to the serialized object.

Comment: So, if the web servers are on different domains they cannot share cookie even though the domain name is the same?  Also, I did not get the 'local' part.  I thought cookies are sent back to the server with each request over the network.

Comment: They are but you said they are likely on two different machines so even if they are on the same domain they wouldn't be sharing the same cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it as long as the domain is same. You just need to explecetly set the cookie path to root.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie name ", "cookie value");
cookie.setPath("/");
response.setCookie(cookie);
```

Now this cookie will be available to all the application on that domain.

suppose there are two application

- www.example.com/app1
- www.example.com/app2

now this cookie will available to both `app1` and `app2`.